# Extract Information from multiple workbooks into a master workbook using Define Names

Tags: excel, vba

First off, I have workbooks that all have defined names in the data, but the data is scattered.

I want to create a procedure that loops through all the define names in the workbooks with the information, take the data from the intersection of two names, take it back to the master sheet, search for the relevant Define Names and paste the information in the intersecting cells.
 I know you can search for names using the Names command. I'm still to inexperience to put it into action.

Thank you again for the help.

Here the code I wrote so far.

```
Sub Workbook()

Dim source1 As Integer, source2 As Integer, master1 As Integer, master2 As Integer


source1 = Application.Workbooks("Vba Cost Budget").Worksheets("Costs").Range("Bottles").Column
source2 = Application.Workbooks("Vba Cost Budget").Worksheets("costs").Range("Variable_labor").Row

master1 = Application.Workbooks("Budget Template").Worksheets("Dataset").Range("Bottles").Column
master2 = Application.Workbooks("Budget Template").Worksheets("Dataset").Range("Variable_labor").Row

Application.Workbooks("Budget Template").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(master1, master2) = Application.Workbooks("Vba Bottling Variable Cost Budget").Worksheets("costs").Cells(source1, source2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Does that not work ? - what happens when you run it?

Comment: It works, it takes the intersection of bottling/variable labor from cost and the intersection of bottling/variable labor in budget template and matches them up, putting the source data into main sheet. I have 100+ define names and writing/copying paste is a huge pain, trying to figure out a loop. Or if you know a better way of extracting information from multiple workbooks, that be great too =)

Comment: You could rename the sub you posted and add two string-type parameters, and then use those in the following lines in place of the hard-coded range names.  You could then call it like (eg) `TransferValue "Bottles", "Variable_labor"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over worksheet named ranges using the names collection

```
For Each namedRange In Application.Workbooks("Vba Cost Budget").Worksheets("Costs").Names
    ...
Next namedRange
```